# How does one test payments using a test app without registering a new company?

Tags: facebook, testing, payment

I am trying to use an app created as a test app from the main, production app (that has a company registered). However, the test app isn't using the company from the main app, and I just see the button to register a new company.

How does one test payments using the main company (or none at all)?